# Why am I getting an AttributeError when I have the attribute?

Tags: python, attributeerror

I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: Caribou instance has no attribute 'on_key_up'
```

The problem is, I'm pretty sure I do have that attribute...

Here are some excerpts from my code (from caribou.py):

```
 def on_key_up(self, event):
  if event.event_string == "Shift_R":
   _r_shift_down = False
  elif event.event_string == "Shift_L":
   _l_shift_down = False
```

And this is the line that is causing the error:

```
pyatspi.Registry.registerKeystrokeListener(caribou.on_key_up, mask=None, kind=(pyatspi.KEY_RELEASED_EVENT,))
```

Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

edit: Whoops--here's how I create the caribou instance:

```
caribou = Caribou()
```

Comment: You should show us the entire file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP mentions in a comment that `dir(caribou)` gives him:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

so it **definitely** looks at that point that `caribou` is a **module** -- nothing else would normally have `__builtins__` etc.  The error message however clearly mentions a `Caribou instance` -- so I imagine that something else **must** be happening between that `dir` call and the following attempt to access `caribou.on_key_up`.

Clearly the OP is having some multiple use of that beloved `caribou` identifier (at some point it's bound to a Caribou instance, but at other times it's clearly a module, and indeed the OP does mention a `caribou.py` which is clearly going to become a module named `caribou` when imported).

So my recommendation is to **clarify** naming.  For example, use

```
caribou_instance = Caribou()
```

instead of binding one more value to the `caribou` name, and replace all uses of `caribou` which are supposed to be the instance (not the module) with `caribou_instance`.  That may give you a different error, which could be more informative.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you print dir(caribou)? Do you see your method?

Comment: This is what I see:

['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']

It's weird though, because I should have a class called 'Caribou' (this is where the on_key_up function is) and a function 'usage'

Comment: do you have a file called....
Caribou.py? In the same folder?

look for any files called import Caribou do you see anything?

Comment: Yea--the file is called 'caribou.py'. Inside that file is the class 'Caribou' and the function 'usage'.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't showing your import statements or how "caribou" the **instance** is being created.  My guess is you are trying to pass caribou.on_key_up as in caribou the **module**, not the **instance**.

Comment: I didn't import caribou because I defined the class in the same .py file.  As for how the instance is being created, please see the edit.

Thanks for the reply!